# Chromium embedded framework - attaching/injecting CSS/JS to page (C++ - MFC)

Tags: c++, oop, mfc, chromium, chromium-embedded

I would like to know if it is possible to attach CSS or JS file to page before opening in CEF( Chromium embedded framework  ) in C++ ?

Why i need it is because i have some pages to open via CEF, but the pages's design is too bad, i want to change some styles there.

any tips will be appreciated.

thanks
Gofur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript code can be injected in `CefLoadHandler::OnLoadStart` by calling `frame->ExecuteJavascript`.

Comment: Thank you Czarek! i want to style scrolls, what do yo think what would be best solution to style scrolls of all chromium windows?

Comment: @user3057239 You inject CSS through javascript.